# Simpson's rule using Taylor polynomial

Tags: simpsons-rule

From a proof of Simpson's rule using Taylor polynomial where $f\in[x_{0},x_{2}]$ and, for 
$$x_{1}=x_{0}+h$$
where
$$h=\frac{x_{2}-x_{0}}{2}$$,
it got:
$$\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{2}}f(x)dx\cong2hf(x_{1})+h^{3}\frac{f''(x_{1})}{3}+h^{5}\frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{60}$$
and then, it changed $f''(x_{1})$ by
$$\frac{f(x_{0})-2f(x_{1})+f(x_{2})}{h^{2}}$$
And I don't know from where it came.

Comment: That's the central difference quotient for $f''$

Comment: One way to approximate the second derivative is through [finite difference methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences). The second-order central finite difference is

$$f''(x) =  \frac{f(x-h) - 2 f(x) + f(x+h)}{h^{2}}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$

where at $x=x_1$

$$f''(x_1) \approx  \frac{f(x_0) - 2 f(x_1) + f(x_2)}{h^{2}}$$

Do you have any other questions about the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the proof replaces $f''(x_1)$ with its [second-order central finite difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences). Given a small $h>0$ which represents the difference between grid points $x_j$ and $x_{j-1}$, the formula can be derived by adding the two Taylor expansions

$$f(x-h)=f(x)-hf'(x)+\frac{h^2f''(x)}{2!}-\frac{h^3f'''(x)}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(h^4)$$
and
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2f''(x)}{2!}+\frac{h^3f'''(x)}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(h^4)$$

to form

$$f(x-h)+f(x+h)=2f(x)+h^2f''(x)+\mathcal{O}(h^4)$$

which after subtracting $2f(x)$ and dividing by $h^2$ produces

$$f''(x)\approx \frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$$

in your case the grid points are $x=x_1$, $x-h=x_0$, and $x+h=x_2$ therefore

$$f''(x_1)\approx \frac{f(x_0)-2f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{h^2}$$